Why am I facing this issue when building a React app? Even though I have the latest version of Node js installed
Why does this problem appear when I create a new React file specifically using this code:
npx create-react-app movies
Even though the latest version of Node.js has been installed
'Omar\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252
throw err;

^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Hamza \node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1249:15)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.11.0
PS E:\movies>


If you have a build folder try to remove it and build the application again. Also good idea to clean npm cache. That is what usually works for me.
